# Putting 3 values on a checkbox

Tags: php

Noob here. Is there a way where I can put 2 numeric values and 1 alphabetical value in a single check box and display all values of it by using php.

```
    <input name='ts[]' type='checkbox' value='40 | Tosilog' /> Tosilog

       $ts = $_POST['ts'];  
       $value = explode("|",$ts[0] );
       echo $value[0]; echo $value[1];
```

I just want to add another numeric value.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Could you exemplify with some sample data or even sample code?

Comment: How does that make sense? A checkbox is either on or off (well, or indeterminate if we are being picky). Do you have some code to demonstrate what you need?

Comment: You have to do it with HTML. engaging PHP will be bad idea

Comment: You will have far more code exploding the values and verifying that the array indexes exist to manipulate than you will if you just declare them in your php file to begin with. Not to mention, a troll comes along and decides to change `value` to `value="something you didn't check for"` and submits and breaks your code or worse depending on what you are doing with these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: ?

```
<input name='ts[]' type='checkbox' value='40 | Tosilog | 1337' /> Tosilog
<?php   
$ts = $_POST['ts']; 
$value = explode("|",$ts[0] );  
echo $value[0]; 
echo $value[1];
echo $value[2];
```

But, that's, like people said above, very ugly. 
Might want to explain what you're trying to accomplice here.

Comment: It worked! but I need to know now how can I  get the third value for my computation. FOr example, if I checked the box the third value will be multiplied by 10.
Hope my grammar is correct. Im bad at english. :)

Comment: $yourval = (int)$value[2] * 10;